# PHP 7 laravel dompdf - can't make deployed version to work

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf

I've issue with deploying code to client server, I'm using barryvdh laravel dompdf extension, the issue is everything works fine on my test vps, while I can't make it work on server of my customer, I keep on receiving error

```
`No block-level parent found. Not good.`
```

I did research on this and nothing worked so far, I did composer update, also double checked and all files are in place, also tried removing spaces from html, but it still doesn't work, any suggestions? Any reasons it doesn't work? Any way to copy/list my configuration from my vps to customer one?

[screenshot of error stacktrace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKQrM.png)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
 <title>Document</title>
 <style>
        tbody:before,
        tbody:after {
            display: none;
        }

        .title {
            font-size: 30px;
            color: #071d8c;
            font-weight: 700;
            text-align: left;
            letter-spacing: -0.65px;
            padding-bottom: 20px;
        }

        .time, .difficulty, .portions, .wallet {
            width: 30px;
        }

        .details-text {
            display: inline-block;
            margin-left: 6px;
        }
        .time p{
            display: inline-block;
        }
        .time img,
        .difficulty img,
        .portions img,
        .wallet img {
            display: inline-block;
            position: relative;
            top: 5px;
        }

        * {
            font-family: "DejaVu Sans";
        }

        .ingredients {
            background-color: #f7f7f7;
        }
        .ingredients h2{
            padding: 0 15px;
            color: #071d8c;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #071d8c;
        }
        .ingredients ul {
            list-style-type: none;
            padding-left: 0;
            margin-left: 15px;

        }
        .ingredients ul li{
            border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
            padding-bottom: 3px
            margin-bottom: 3px
        }
        .preparation {
            padding: 0 15px;
        }
        .preparation h2{
            color: #071d8c;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #071d8c;
        }

        .preparation ul {
            padding: 0 20px 5px 15px;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
        }
        tr td{
            margin-right: 0px;
        }
        .details-text{
            margin-right: 30px;
        }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
<table class="main">
 <tr><td class="title" colspan="2">{{$recipe['name']}}</td> </tr>
 <tr><td class="photo">
            @if ( ! empty($images))
                @foreach($images as $index => $image)
                    @if($index >= 3)
                        @break
                    @endif
     @if (! empty($image->image))
                     <img src="{{ '.' . ($image->image . '_big.jpg')}}" alt="{{$recipe['name']}}">
                     <br><br>
     @endif
                @endforeach
            @endif
  </td>
  <td class="content" style="vertical-align: top;">
   <table class="content_table">
    <tr class="details">
     <td><table>
       <tr>
        <td class="time"><img src="img/timer.png" alt="Czas"></td><td><p class="details-text">{{ $recipe['cooking_time']['time'] }}</p></td>
       </tr>
      </table>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <table><tr>
       <td class="ingredients" style="vertical-align: top;">
        <h2>Ingredients</h2>
        @foreach($recipe['to_buy'] as $toBuy)
         <h3>{{$toBuy->title}}</h3>
         <ul>
          @foreach($toBuy->steps as $step)
           <li>{{$step}}</li>
          @endforeach
         </ul>
        @endforeach
       </td>
       <td class="preparation">
        <h2>Preparation</h2>
        @foreach($recipe['steps'] as $step)
         <h3>{{$step->title}}</h3>
         <ul>
          <li>{!! strip_tags($step->text) !!}</li>
         </ul>
        @endforeach
        @if (! empty($recipe['advices']))
         <h2>Advices</h2>
         @foreach ($recipe['advices'] as $advice)
          <li>
           {!! $advice !!}
          </li>
         @endforeach
        @endif
       </td>
      </tr>
     </table>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
  public function download (Recipes $recipe)
    {
        $recipeToSend = $this->retrieveRecipeToSend($recipe);
        $images = json_decode($recipe->steps);


        $pdf = new DOMPDF();

        return PDF::loadView('pdf.recipe', ['recipe' => $recipeToSend, 'images' => $images])
                  ->setOptions(['debugCss' => false, 'debugLayout' => false, 'default Font' => 'sans-serif', 'isHtml5ParserEnabled' => true])
                  ->setPaper('a3', 'portrait')
                  ->download('recipe.pdf');
    }
```

Comment: can you share your html ? and version of dompdf using in both local and live ?

Comment: my dompdf version: "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.8.1",

Comment: Both in local and live ?

Comment: yes, theyre exactly same on local and live

Comment: Can you try by removing `<br><br>` or try `<br/><br/>` ?

Comment: yeah, I did it, currently waiting for deploy, do you have any other guesses?

Comment: other than php and dompdf version and this `<br/>` tag no guess as of now, just try and let me know ?

Comment: @user2486 I replaced <br> with <br/> and it didn't work, tried without br doesn't work either, I have no clue

Comment: You are only the place where you can hit and run , by remove half code and rerun, you understand what I am saying? may be is any html special character error, but can remove some part any try if still not work just pass small part and then try try try. good luck

Comment: @user2486 I tried editing html but no solution so far, so I removed whole html and replaced ith with 'it works' and it showed me this string in pdf, but when I include any html it returns error

Comment: did you include whole html or just a part like `<div> it works </div>` ?

Comment: @user2486 I DID IT! I removed ALL whitespaces which were not needed by php tempalte engine or html and it finally worked!

Comment: Wow great means problem was with whitespaces